# How to call this value in blade

Tags: php, laravel

I am looking for fetch values from DB i wrote this in controller

```
$amount= DB::table('payments')
        ->select(DB::raw('donatorName'), DB::raw('sum(donationApplied)'))
        ->groupBy(DB::raw('donatorName') )
        ->get();
```

its showing correct in DD() or prin_r,  but i can't fetch result in blade with foreach loop  please guide  me what to or where is mistake?

its showing correct in DD() or prin_r,  but i can't fetch result in blade with foreach loop  please guide  me what to or where is mistake?

Comment: What's with the raw usage?

Comment: how you are sending data to blade and how you are reading data in blade ?

Comment: where is your view file, what is it's name. have you tried returning the view ? Why do you use `\DB::raw()` when you dont need it.

Comment: Iam using laravel query builder method , I need specific raws to fetch in blade

Answer (score 0):

As refered here https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/views you can pass data to the view from the controller like so: `return view('admin.profile', $data);`

there you just have to use

```
@foreach ($data as $item)
    <p> {{$item}}</p>
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 0):

From controller to a blade file access variable many ways:
But, I recommend using the `compact()` method.
if you would return more then one variable use `compact('data', 'data1', 'data2')`

`1`:

```
public function index(){
     $amount= DB::table('payments')
         ->select(DB::raw('donatorName'), DB::raw('sum(donationApplied)'))
         ->groupBy(DB::raw('donatorName') )
         ->get();
     return view('admin.profile', compact('data'));
}
```

`2`:

```
public function index(){
     $amount= DB::table('payments')
         ->select(DB::raw('donatorName'), DB::raw('sum(donationApplied)'))
         ->groupBy(DB::raw('donatorName') )
         ->get();
     return view('admin.profile', array('data' => $data));
}
```

`3`:

```
public function index(){
     $amount= DB::table('payments')
         ->select(DB::raw('donatorName'), DB::raw('sum(donationApplied)'))
         ->groupBy(DB::raw('donatorName') )
         ->get();
     return view('admin.profile')->with('data', $data);
}
```